# Need help to make subdivisions square 2.9

Tags: subdivision-surface, sculpt, remesh

going crazy here... im pretty new to blender and im trying to model a tomb (will use it as a 3d printed pen display) but i want to add texture. Problem is that when i go to sculpt/remesh 0.01 it provides lots of faces but they are all rectangle. im pretty sure thats why my paintbrush looks elongated and not a circle. need some advice please - ive spent hours on youtube with no result :( . Notice the blue brush in second pic, first pic is model im trying to sculpt.
[image]
Thanks!!

[image: pic1]

Comment: 2 thoughts come to mind. First, try applying scale (in object mode, select the object and press Ctrl+A and select "scale"). If that doesn't work, try adding a loop cut through the center (widthwise) before doing the remesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to apply all the transformations. Press ctrl+A a tab will show up and in that select apply all transforms.I hope this works.